# How to pass a key, value generated by a Lambda function to KMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-kms, aws-parameter-store

I have the following typescript code that generates a key that I need to store in KMS

```
import {LocalCryptUtils} from 'crypt-util';

const fs = require('fs');

const cryptUtils = new LocalCryptUtils();
cryptUtils.createMasterPrivateKey();

var file = fs.createWriteStream('../../config/derived.txt')
file.write('{\n');
file.write(` "public_key_derived" : "${cryptUtils.derivePublicKey(0, 0)}", \n`)
file.write(` "public_address_derived" : "${cryptUtils.deriveAddress(0, 0)}" \n`)
file.end('}\n');

console.log(`{ "masterKey" : "${cryptUtils.exportMasterPrivateKey()}" }`);
```

All the resources I found on the internet are explaining how to include KMS or Parameter Store variables within a Lambda function. But my requirement is reverse that. I need to use a Lambda function to generate a key and store in KMS, and one other smaller function to generate a key and store in Parameter Store. As a result use that in ECS Fargate.

I would appreciate your guidance with this.

PS. I'm using Terraform as IaC tool.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to achieve. KMS can create customer managed keys by calling the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/APIReference/API_CreateKey.html API but that generates the key and doesn't give you access to it. You then call KMS APIs to encrypt or decrypt data with that key. Could you maybe explain what you're trying to achieve as a complete thing rather than the steps you think you need to do to achieve that thing instead please?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I deleted my previous comment as I realised I again it did no provide enough info. So here I'm giving it another shot; We are using this code to generate a key `the key` and store it manually in Parameter Store and then encrypt it with KMS. Then provided the right permissions to ECS Fargate use `the key` in wherever the application requires. I'm concerned in this generation part of this key and think its better to get rid of it, but I don't see a generation feature in Store Parameter or Secrets Manager. Are such keys always generated outside of the infra and manually stored in AWS?

Comment: There's still probably not enough context as to why you're doing this very specific thing but maybe I can explain what we do when we need to generate some secret string or key to be used by a service. We use the [`random_password`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/random/latest/docs/resources/password) resource to have Terraform generate something on the fly and store it in the state file (which is secured separately) and then use the [`aws_ssm_parameter`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssm_parameter) resource to store it in SSM.

Comment: For ECS services you can use `secrets` in the ECS task definition to reference an SSM parameter by its ARN and then we allow the task execution role the IAM permissions to get it and decrypt it (we encrypt with a CMK KMS key to prevent read only users reading secrets). Then the service just reads it from an environment variable during runtime.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR you actually explained exactly what I was looking for. So I think we just need to convert what we have in this code parameters to create the password to the `random_password` terraform resource. As far as I checked the documentation there are many parameters in this resource where you can customise to create a password. But this generated password is kind of a onetime generation or maybe changes very rarely. We have to somehow prevent it from recreation when there is an update in the resources and terraform scripts, do you have an idea about that?